# 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'The memcache extension must be loaded for using this backend !' through shell_exec()

Tags: php, zend-framework, memcached, shell-exec

found a strange error when I call a PHP script (**process.php**) through **shell_exec()**
message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'The memcache extension must be loaded for using this backend !' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/shared_lib/ZendFramework/1.5.2-patched/Zend/Cache.php:208
```

But, I can call the process.php **without any error if I call it in the terminal**.

Pseudo Code:

**control.php**

```
// some business logic ....
shell_exec("php process.php");
// some business logic ....
```

**process.php**

```
// some business logic ....
call Zend_Cache to retrieve data from memecache
// some business logic ....
```

Comment: `php -i |grep loaded -i`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify different php.ini files in http.conf (of vhosts.conf). PHP will use the one in the path by default (which will happen when you run hte comment line) but in apache you can tell it to load a different one.

Check for a line like

```
PHPINIDir /etc/local/php
```

(the PHPINIDir being the improtant bit!) in httpd.conf/vhosts.conf and that will be the file you are using through apache that has memcached. Then check the php.ini file being used by the command line ($ php -i | grep 'Configuration File') and see if different. It it is, use "php -c XXX/php.ini" to tell the command line to use the same ini file as apache.